# how override creat method in sale order odoo 10 to add po RFQ

Tags: odoo, purchase-order

I am try to override create method in sale order to make purchase order with current data in sale order and my code did not work
Iam try this:

```
@api.multi
```

def creat(self):
    # for order in self:
    #     order.state = 'sale'
    #     order.confirmation_date = fields.Datetime.now()
    #     if self.env.context.get('send_email'):
    #         self.force_quotation_send()
    #     order.order_line._action_procurement_create()
    # if self.env['ir.values'].get_default('sale.config.settings', 'auto_done_setting'):
    #     self.action_done()

```
    self.env['purchase.order'].create({'partner_id': partner_id.id,
        'location_id':location_id.id,
        'pricelist_id': pricelist_id.id,
        'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id': product_id.id,
           'name': name.id,
           'date_planned': date_planned.id,
            'price_unit': price_unit.id})]})
    return True
```

Comment: your code is not clear, from where did you get value for variables product_id, name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use api.model for create method as there is no id for the record when creating a new record.

here is a sample code

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
    # Your code here 
    # vals will contain dictionary of all variables.      
    return res
```

Also You don't have to change code for creating purchase order from sales.
You just have to set routes(Buy in this case) for the product and product's vendor.